# Windows Threading C++ - Access Violation

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I am new to threading for Windows and would appreciate any and all suggestions.  I have created a small program to demonstrate the access violation I am getting. 
Here is test.h:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

using namespace std;

#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string> 
#include <vector>

/**************************************************************************************************/
template<typename T>
string toString(const T&x){

        stringstream output;
        output << x;
        return output.str();    
}

/**************************************************************************************************/
//custom data structure for threads to use.
// This is passed by void pointer so it can be any data type
// that can be passed using a single void pointer (LPVOID).
struct tempData {
    int threadID;
    vector<string> filenames;

    tempData(){}
    tempData(vector<string> f, int tid) {
        filenames = f;
        threadID = tid;
    }
 };

 /**************************************************************************************************/
 static DWORD WINAPI tempThreadFunction(LPVOID lpParam){ 
    tempData* pDataArray;
    pDataArray = (tempData*)lpParam;

            string fileName = pDataArray->filenames[pDataArray->threadID];
            ifstream fileHandle(fileName.c_str());
            string output = toString(pDataArray->threadID);
            ofstream out(output.c_str());

            string name;
            int currentNum, num;
            vector<string> nameVector;
            vector<float> data;
            float currentData;
            int index = 0;

            fileHandle >> num;

            while(!fileHandle.eof()){

                fileHandle >> name >> currentNum; 
                nameVector.push_back(name);

                for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
                    fileHandle >> currentData;
                    data.push_back(currentData);
                }

                //grab extra white space
                char d;
                while(isspace(d=fileHandle.get()))      { ;}
                if(!fileHandle.eof()) { fileHandle.putback(d); }

                index++;

                cout << "Thread " << pDataArray->threadID << '\t' << index << endl;
                out << name << '\t' << "Thread " << pDataArray->threadID << '\t' << index << endl;
            }

            fileHandle.close();
            out.close();

            cout << "Thread " << pDataArray->threadID << " read " << nameVector.size() << " lines." << endl;
    }
#endif
```

And here is test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"

/**************************************************************************************************/
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    string fileName1 = argv[1];
    string fileName2 = argv[2];

    vector<string> fileNames; fileNames.push_back(fileName1);  fileNames.push_back(fileName2); 

    vector<tempData*> pDataArray; 
    DWORD   dwThreadIdArray[2];
    HANDLE  hThreadArray[2]; 

    //Create processor worker threads.
    for( int i=0; i<2; i++ ){
    // Allocate memory for thread data. 
        tempData* tempThread = new tempData(fileNames, i);
        pDataArray.push_back(tempThread);

        hThreadArray[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, tempThreadFunction, pDataArray[i], 0, &dwThreadIdArray[i]);   
    }

        //Wait until all threads have terminated.
    WaitForMultipleObjects(2, hThreadArray, TRUE, INFINITE);

    //Close all thread handles and free memory allocations.
    for(int i=0; i < pDataArray.size(); i++){
        CloseHandle(hThreadArray[i]);
        delete pDataArray[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
 /**************************************************************************************************/
```

The files the threads are reading look like:

```
 450
 F5MMO9001C96XU 450 1.03 0.02 1.00 0.03 0.05 1.02 0.03 1.04 0.05 0.04 2.06 1.05 2.01 0.05 0.98 0.03 0.08 1.05 1.01 0.02 0.05 1.03 0.04 0.04 2.05 1.07 2.04 1.01 0.06 0.05 0.96 2.02 0.06 0.04 0.99 0.06 1.00 0.03 0.06 1.04 0.08 0.01 1.07 0.06 1.02 0.03 0.05 2.00 0.07 0.04 1.00 0.11 0.06 1.01 1.02 1.02 1.03 1.06 0.04 1.04 1.94 1.02 0.06 1.00 0.12 0.06 2.01 1.96 0.94 0.08 0.10 0.96 0.12 0.05 1.01 0.05 2.04 1.11 0.08 0.04 2.00 0.06 1.02 0.04 1.99 0.05 1.03 0.09 0.14 0.98 0.10 1.99 1.02 1.06 2.11 1.00 0.96 0.10 1.00 0.08 0.11 1.08 0.07 0.06 1.03 0.10 0.04 1.01 0.12 1.11 0.09 0.99 0.98 0.12 3.06 0.15 0.12 1.03 0.17 2.00 1.01 0.98 0.06 0.16 2.00 1.00 0.08 1.06 0.19 0.13 2.10 0.13 0.08 1.00 0.19 0.99 0.16 2.00 2.19 0.12 3.96 0.17 0.99 0.05 2.06 0.06 3.03 0.08 1.02 0.06 0.11 1.02 0.17 1.01 1.06 0.15 0.08 3.92 0.14 1.01 0.13 0.12 1.05 2.04 3.04 1.02 0.98 0.08 0.10 2.02 3.19 1.00 0.11 1.98 0.14 1.94 0.14 0.07 2.04 0.08 2.05 0.06 0.98 0.08 1.99 0.04 2.93 1.07 0.11 0.05 1.04 0.17 0.09 0.97 1.05 0.99 0.08 0.11 1.02 1.98 0.07 0.06 1.05 0.06 0.09 1.03 0.17 0.11 1.05 0.14 0.09 2.09 0.19 0.06 1.02 0.13 1.03 0.06 0.15 2.07 0.19 0.98 0.08 0.06 1.06 0.16 1.09 0.14 0.16 1.00 0.17 2.07 0.13 0.13 1.01 0.08 2.04 0.05 0.18 1.03 0.05 0.02 0.99 1.01 0.09 0.07 2.98 0.07 0.13 1.01 0.04 0.10 1.99 0.15 0.15 1.05 1.01 0.01 2.09 0.16 0.13 4.02 0.19 0.06 2.03 0.10 3.97 0.08 0.09 1.01 1.01 0.08 1.03 0.16 0.09 1.03 0.12 0.05 1.02 0.07 1.04 0.04 0.15 1.01 0.13 0.04 1.91 0.10 1.06 0.08 2.99 1.01 1.01 1.00 0.04 1.93 0.13 0.90 0.16 1.01 0.98 0.04 1.14 0.16 1.06 0.05 0.13 3.00 0.12 0.05 2.10 0.99 0.99 0.03 0.09 1.00 1.01 0.04 0.99 0.04 1.02 0.08 1.02 0.14 0.11 0.98 0.20 1.15 1.06 0.06 3.08 0.08 0.09 0.97 0.00 0.97 1.04 0.15 0.12 0.89 0.94 0.05 0.12 2.04 0.14 0.04 1.15 0.11 1.06 0.04 0.08 2.10 1.05 0.03 1.01 0.98 1.04 0.03 2.00 0.03 1.01 0.03 0.91 0.10 1.04 0.08 1.04 0.14 0.03 0.98 0.15 1.13 0.12 0.92 2.14 0.09 0.11 0.96 0.07 1.04 0.13 0.03 1.02 0.05 1.12 1.06 1.00 0.13 0.04 0.88 0.01 1.10 0.14 0.88 0.14 0.10 1.10 0.00 1.14 1.01 1.02 0.06 0.95 1.86 0.07 0.04 1.01 0.04 1.93 0.04 0.08 2.05 1.10 0.10 0.11 0.91 0.11 1.00 0.08 1.09 0.07 0.10 2.14 0.10 3.19 1.07 2.10 0.11 1.02 0.13 0.93 0.09 0.13 0.90 2.17 0.09 0.19 2.09 1.10 0.09 1.13 0.91 2.03 0.08 1.01 2.09 0.19 0.07 1.03 0.10 
 F5MMO9001DCOF4 450 0.98 0.02 1.03 0.02 0.04 1.04 0.02 1.02 0.03 0.05 2.15 1.04 2.01 0.00 0.93 0.07 0.06 1.01 0.99 0.03 0.05 1.02 0.05 0.02 2.06 1.10 2.02 0.98 0.09 0.06 1.05 2.03 0.08 0.05 1.01 0.10 1.03 0.03 0.09 1.00 0.07 0.01 1.02 0.07 0.98 0.03 0.05 1.98 0.10 0.01 1.02 0.10 0.05 1.03 1.09 1.02 1.02 1.04 0.06 0.99 1.98 0.98 0.07 1.00 0.12 0.04 2.09 1.03 1.00 0.00 0.17 2.02 0.11 0.03 0.96 0.13 2.02 0.04 2.11 0.05 1.03 0.00 1.11 1.07 2.92 1.02 1.02 0.08 0.93 1.03 2.02 0.99 1.01 0.08 1.05 0.09 0.13 1.00 0.11 0.01 2.00 0.11 0.06 1.03 0.18 0.05 1.04 0.07 0.05 1.99 0.11 0.01 0.99 0.16 0.05 1.04 0.11 0.05 1.04 0.13 0.07 1.02 0.11 0.06 2.17 0.10 0.03 1.04 2.07 0.03 0.99 0.13 0.09 0.99 1.02 0.00 0.04 0.94 1.04 0.01 0.06 1.05 1.01 0.02 1.10 0.11 0.11 1.01 0.12 0.03 1.03 0.11 0.09 1.01 1.03 1.06 2.02 0.09 0.99 1.06 1.03 0.03 1.03 0.12 0.17 0.88 0.16 0.02 1.11 2.86 1.07 0.03 0.15 2.10 1.01 0.02 0.04 0.91 0.15 0.99 0.03 1.01 0.06 1.07 0.09 0.16 1.05 0.13 3.03 1.00 1.07 0.05 0.16 0.99 0.13 0.98 0.08 0.90 2.01 1.05 0.08 2.74 0.20 0.16 1.01 0.20 2.07 0.04 2.05 0.11 1.08 0.03 0.16 1.05 0.10 0.02 0.97 0.08 0.99 0.04 0.19 1.02 1.03 0.03 1.08 0.10 1.04 0.05 0.16 1.06 1.01 0.99 0.06 0.15 1.02 1.92 0.13 0.06 1.02 1.02 2.06 0.04 0.09 1.09 0.15 0.01 0.98 0.08 1.06 0.01 2.06 1.02 1.01 0.04 1.08 0.12 0.09 0.90 0.11 0.99 0.17 1.03 1.14 0.08 2.84 0.04 0.86 0.94 1.37 0.08 2.05 0.19 0.16 0.94 0.35 0.11 2.00 0.20 0.18 0.93 0.41 0.15 0.96 2.03 0.16 1.75 0.19 1.45 0.14 1.27 0.04 0.17 2.11 0.23 3.92 0.13 0.32 1.02 2.03 0.07 1.05 0.27 0.30 1.06 0.29 0.08 0.99 0.24 1.04 0.02 0.31 1.03 0.24 0.05 1.93 0.21 0.98 0.09 3.70 1.02 1.44 1.03 0.84 2.42 0.24 1.23 0.09 1.49 2.89 0.24 0.21 3.26 0.93 0.10 2.19 1.98 1.00 0.03 0.45 1.27 1.30 0.02 0.83 0.26 1.17 0.05 1.19 0.12 0.23 0.85 0.20 1.00 0.98 0.15 2.58 0.21 0.27 1.72 0.90 0.16 0.88 0.38 0.01 1.08 1.20 0.12 0.16 2.01 0.24 0.03 1.88 1.39 1.83 0.06 1.36 0.21 0.39 0.87 0.19 0.12 0.84 0.19 1.69 0.09 1.13 0.09 1.42 0.09 1.24 0.09 1.11 0.09 0.21 0.81 0.20 0.93 0.16 1.06 1.70 2.08 0.15 0.16 1.42 0.43 1.06 0.86 1.20 0.12 1.22 0.20 0.25 0.98 0.23 0.82 0.19 0.25 1.01 0.18 1.05 0.11 0.26 0.95 0.22 0.11 1.08 0.19 1.05 1.03 0.21 0.08 2.14 0.21 1.84 0.07 0.40 1.79 1.35 0.90 0.17 1.35 1.12 0.15 1.84 1.23 2.19 0.86 1.35 0.26 0.34 1.00 
 F5MMO9001CUZ4G 450 1.04 0.01 1.02 0.03 0.04 1.00 0.02 1.01 0.04 0.08 2.06 1.02 1.97 0.03 0.99 0.05 0.07 1.07 1.03 0.02 0.06 1.03 0.05 0.02 1.99 1.04 2.06 0.99 0.09 0.05 1.01 1.98 0.08 0.06 1.00 0.06 1.03 0.05 0.05 1.02 0.11 0.04 1.03 0.06 1.04 0.03 0.06 2.04 0.09 0.05 0.98 0.08 0.06 1.03 1.02 1.03 0.98 1.05 0.07 1.01 1.95 1.05 0.05 1.00 0.11 0.05 2.03 1.96 1.02 0.01 0.11 1.03 0.12 0.02 0.98 0.07 1.97 0.03 1.02 0.04 3.03 1.01 3.02 0.05 0.17 1.01 0.19 0.06 2.00 1.05 2.07 1.03 1.01 0.10 1.04 0.09 0.12 1.03 1.04 0.04 1.01 0.12 1.03 0.05 0.09 1.02 1.00 1.01 0.09 0.12 1.06 0.12 2.01 0.01 0.99 1.05 1.03 0.06 1.05 0.10 0.12 1.02 1.03 0.06 0.05 1.00 0.11 2.00 0.07 0.14 0.98 1.05 0.07 3.04 0.13 1.05 0.12 0.07 1.03 2.03 3.07 1.02 0.99 0.16 0.05 1.98 3.08 0.96 0.08 1.97 0.10 1.96 0.08 0.10 1.98 1.03 1.04 0.07 1.03 0.13 0.16 1.03 0.20 0.07 1.01 0.14 3.08 0.97 0.14 0.05 1.09 0.15 0.06 1.02 1.00 1.01 0.06 0.12 1.02 1.99 0.11 0.03 1.01 0.98 2.02 0.02 0.18 1.06 0.14 0.02 1.03 0.15 1.00 0.03 0.15 1.02 0.15 0.04 1.04 0.13 0.09 0.99 0.16 0.06 1.03 0.15 1.05 0.10 0.16 1.01 0.18 1.99 0.14 0.09 1.05 0.09 1.99 0.04 2.05 1.03 0.10 0.05 3.14 0.15 0.14 1.01 0.11 0.07 2.01 0.12 0.09 0.96 1.00 0.03 0.09 1.02 0.19 0.08 1.03 0.15 0.12 2.14 0.18 0.05 1.02 1.06 0.18 0.04 2.00 0.09 4.08 0.05 0.13 0.98 1.08 0.09 1.03 0.14 0.10 1.00 0.12 0.02 1.01 0.09 1.03 0.04 0.15 0.99 0.12 0.03 2.06 0.10 1.09 0.08 3.21 1.03 1.01 0.99 0.09 2.01 0.15 0.93 0.13 1.02 0.95 0.13 1.02 0.17 1.06 0.05 0.16 3.12 0.12 0.08 2.07 1.06 1.08 1.02 0.09 0.07 0.93 0.13 1.01 0.07 0.98 0.07 1.02 0.11 0.12 0.99 0.21 1.09 1.08 0.10 3.03 0.06 0.12 1.99 0.04 0.12 1.00 0.03 0.11 1.05 1.00 0.07 0.16 1.96 0.12 0.04 2.16 1.98 1.04 0.07 0.90 0.04 0.15 1.09 3.08 0.10 1.04 0.15 0.99 0.08 1.05 0.08 1.07 0.17 0.07 1.01 0.18 2.06 0.13 0.13 2.12 1.97 0.14 0.09 0.91 0.10 1.07 1.09 3.06 1.08 0.98 0.17 0.91 0.09 0.08 3.09 0.11 1.08 0.19 0.00 2.04 0.16 2.05 0.17 0.06 2.07 0.96 2.05 0.09 0.98 0.09 0.06 2.37 0.03 0.16 1.11 0.95 0.09 1.13 0.93 4.07 0.08 0.07 0.95 1.99 0.09 0.12 1.97 1.12 0.11 0.10 2.06 0.18 0.94 0.13 0.09 1.07 0.09 1.03 0.14 0.11 0.98 0.15 1.04 0.15 0.10 1.04 2.06 0.12 1.00 0.07 0.13 2.06 0.94 0.11 0.16 1.03 0.90 0.13 1.03 0.21 1.03 1.09 0.13 2.06 0.06 0.12 1.01 0.10 0.12 1.03 0.06 4.01 0.13 0.06 1.99 
...
```

I don't mind sending the full files if you think it would be helpful.  I suspect it's a simple error having to do with an assumption I am making about threads, but I can't seem to spot it.  Thanks for taking the time to look at this issue.  I really appreciate it!

Comment: I don't believe `cout` is required to be thread safe...

Comment: It looks like this program takes command line and file inputs.  What inputs did you supply?  What is the expected output and the actual output?  Is there are any way you could simplify the program more?  See http://sscce.org for tips.

Comment: On what line are you getting an access violation?  You did use a debugger, didn't you?

Comment: Also, `cout` could produce intermixed output as well. It should at least be exclusive (only one thread executing the `cout` code at a time.

Comment: I agree, use printf instead of cout, or synchronize access cout. Otherwise, I do not see any multi-threading related access violations.

Comment: @DmitryShkuropatsky: `printf` isn't required to be thread safe either.

Comment: I can't see much wrong either, except maybe the cout issue already mentioned.  The thread parameter is a bit too complex for my liking - I would not pass in the filenames vector to every thread - but even so, should work?  Needs debugging.  First - does it work with only one file-processing thread?  If not debug that simpler case first.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your program in VC 6 and I was getting access violation when I create ofstream objects. The following link helped me to solve that access violation. 
http://www.gamedev.net/topic/73037-ofstream-access-violations-when-multi-threading/
Since you haven't provided more information as where you are getting the violation, I can only give this as a hint.